# MySQL JOIN problem

Tags: mysql, join

SOLUTION: If anyone is interested:

```
SELECT login_id, hotel_name, AVG( q1 ) AS q1, AVG( q2 ) AS q2, AVG( q3 ) AS q3, AVG( q4 ) AS q4, AVG( q5 ) AS q5, AVG( q6 ) AS q6, AVG( q7 ) AS q7, AVG( q8 ) AS q8, AVG( q9 ) AS q9, AVG( q10 ) AS q10, AVG( q11 ) AS q11, AVG( q12 ) AS q12, AVG( q13 ) AS q13, AVG( q14 ) AS q14, AVG( q15 ) AS q15, AVG( q16 ) AS q16, AVG( q17 ) AS q17, AVG( q18 ) AS q18, AVG( q19 ) AS q19, AVG( q20 ) AS q20, AVG( q21 ) AS q21, AVG( q22 ) AS q22
FROM thotels_respondents
LEFT JOIN thotels_results ON thotels_respondents.login_id = thotels_results.company
AND q24 =5
AND thotels_results.date =  'NOV2010'
AND thotels_results.brand =  'XYZ'
WHERE 
AND login_id =  '66j8ttk2'
GROUP BY login_id
```

**By moving the thotels_results.date and .brand to before the WHERE clause resolved the issue.**

Morning all,

Hopefully someone will be able to assist - I'm suspecting that I've missed something completely obvious...

I have two tables in MySQL `hotel_respondents` and `hotel_results` - they are joined by `hotel_respondents.login_id = hotel_results.company`

I have the following data in `hotel_results` table:

```
date       brand code      q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  q6  q7  q8  q9  q10 q11 q12 q13 q14 q15 q16 q17 q18 q19 q20 q21 q22 q23 q24 q25

NOV2010 XYZ 66j8ttk2    8   6   4   8   3   8   8   8   7   4   8   7   7   4   7   6   6   7   4   5   7   7   2   1   1
NOV2010 XYZ 66j8ttk2    9   9   5   5   5   5   3   3   9   9   9   5   6   8   6   8   8   5   5   5   6   6   2   1   1
NOV2010 XYZ 66j8ttk2    10  10  7   10  8   10  10  9   8   10  10  10  8   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  1   1   1
NOV2010 XYZ 66j8ttk2    8   6   4   8   3   8   8   8   7   4   8   7   7   4   7   6   6   7   4   5   7   7   2   1   1
NOV2010 XYZ 66j8ttk2    9   10  9   9   7   10  10  10  9   9   9   10  10  8   10  9   10  10  10  10  10  7   1   1   1
NOV2010 XYZ 66j8ttk2    10  10  10  6   10  10  10  10  6   10  10  10  10  1   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  1   2   1
NOV2010 XYZ 66j8ttk2    10  7   6   9   7   9   8   8   8   6   8   7   10  5   9   8   8   8   7   9   8   8   1   2   1
NOV2010 XYZ 66j8ttk2    8   8   7   7   9   9   10  1   8   10  10  9   8   8   9   8   8   7   8   8   8   9   1   2   1
NOV2010 XYZ 66j8ttk2    6   6   5   7   7   5   7   6   5   3   7   4   5   8   5   7   8   7   5   4   7   3   2   2   1
NOV2010 XYZ 66j8ttk2    10  9   10  9   10  10  8   10  9   10  10  9   9   6   9   9   9   10  9   9   9   8   2   3   2
NOV2010 XYZ 66j8ttk2    5   9   2   6   2   2   10  10  6   2   10  2   2   2   5   5   5   10  5   2   8   8   2   4   1
NOV2010 XYZ 66j8ttk2    9   8   5   7   7   9   9   9   10  10  9   7   9   6   8   8   7   8   9   10  7   10  2   4   1
```

Now, in Excel I run an `AVERAGE` for each question where `q24 = 1` and the following results are returned.

```
q1      q2      q3      q4      q5      q6      q7      q8      q9      q10     q11     q12     q13     q14     q15     q16     q17     q18     q19     q20     q21     q22         
8.80    8.20    5.80    8.00    5.20    8.20    7.80    7.60    8.00    7.20    8.80    7.80    7.60    6.80    8.00    7.80    8.00    7.80    6.60    7.00    8.00    7.40
```

No, I can replicate the results in MySQL using the following code:

```
SELECT login_id, hotel_name, AVG (q1) AS q1, AVG (q2) AS q2, AVG (q3) AS q3, AVG (q4) AS q4, AVG (q5) AS q5, AVG (q6) AS q6, AVG (q7) AS q7, AVG (q8) AS q8, AVG (q9) AS q9, AVG (q10) AS q10, AVG (q11) AS q11, AVG (q12) AS q12, AVG (q13) AS q13, AVG (q14) AS q14, AVG (q15) AS q15, AVG (q16) AS q16, AVG (q17) AS q17, AVG (q18) AS q18, AVG (q19) AS q19, AVG (q20) AS q20, AVG (q21) AS q21, AVG (q22) AS q22 FROM thotels_respondents LEFT JOIN thotels_results ON thotels_respondents.login_id = thotels_results.company AND q24 = 1 WHERE thotels_results.brand = 'XYZ' AND thotels_results.date = 'NOV2010' AND login_id = '66j8ttk2' GROUP BY hotel_name;
```

The issue I have is as follows - the code returns the correct set of results in MySQL as long as q24 has any of 1,2,3,4,5 in the table.  However, as you can see from the above data - for q24 there are NO 5's.

So when you run the following code:

```
SELECT login_id, hotel_name, AVG (q1) AS q1, AVG (q2) AS q2, AVG (q3) AS q3, AVG (q4) AS q4, AVG (q5) AS q5, AVG (q6) AS q6, AVG (q7) AS q7, AVG (q8) AS q8, AVG (q9) AS q9, AVG (q10) AS q10, AVG (q11) AS q11, AVG (q12) AS q12, AVG (q13) AS q13, AVG (q14) AS q14, AVG (q15) AS q15, AVG (q16) AS q16, AVG (q17) AS q17, AVG (q18) AS q18, AVG (q19) AS q19, AVG (q20) AS q20, AVG (q21) AS q21, AVG (q22) AS q22 FROM thotels_respondents LEFT JOIN thotels_results ON thotels_respondents.login_id = thotels_results.company AND q24 = 5 WHERE thotels_results.brand = 'XYZ' AND thotels_results.date = 'NOV2010' AND login_id = '66j8ttk2' GROUP BY hotel_name;
```

It doesn't return any data, simply this message:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.2381 sec)
```

What I need for my code and page to work correctly is to actually bring back a series of NULL's when q24 doesn't have responses for 1 to 5 - like so

```
login_id    hotel_name  q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  q6  q7  q8  q9  q10 q11 q12 q13 q14 q15 q16 q17 q18 q19 q20 q21 q22
66j8ttk2    bbcircus    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I have attempted to modify the code to do this but when I do, I end of messing up the calculations - I am sure I am doing something wrong with the `JOIN` but cannot work out where I am going wrong.

Any and all help gratefully received!!!

Thanks in advance,

Homer.

Answer (score 1):

So you resolved it, but you didn't include the explanation - here it is for completeness.

The difference between the two queries provided lie in the fact that one LEFT JOINs on certain condition and the other LEFT JOINs and then applies condition to the results.

Well, the meaning is different - if you first LEFT JOIN and then apply where condition which applies condition to a column from the table on the right side of the LEFT JOIN then it will prune all the rows where right side is missing. This is due to the fact that condition `thotels_results.date =  'NOV2010'` is not true when `thotels_reults.date IS NULL`.

However if the condition is applied in the LEFT JOIN then it does not matter that it is not true - the definition of the LEFT JOIN is - return a row containing NULLs for rows where join condition is FALSE.

Therefore different resultsets - due to the fact that the condition is applied in different sense.

If you want to get the same result with the WHERE you have to replace each condition such as `thotels_results.date =  'NOV2010'` with `thotels_results.date =  'NOV2010' OR thotels_results.date IS NULL` - because you don't want only rows where the field is equal to a value but you want the rows where it is NULL.

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... If you add COUNT(*) to represent totalRecords to your query.  I thinking that should ALWAYS return a result set of zero records even though the count = 0. Don't have MySQL here, but should work.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work DRapp but thanks - have now found a solution.